# Appending masonry element from php for loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, masonry

Hello I'm a novice developer and I am not sure if what I to do is actually possible.

I have created a masonry gallery. When clicking a picture a description appear underneath the image.

After the gallery worked I decided to loop over the pictures in order to "clean the code" but now I am stuck.

I would like to append the paragraph which class match to the picture class... Is that possible?

```
  <div class="grid">
    <?php for ($i=1; $i < 5; $i++){ echo "<div class='grid-item $i'><img src='img/classic-$i.png' class='img-responsive'><p class='description hidden $i'></p></div>";
            } ?>

          <p class="description hidden 1">Content description 1</p>
          <p class="description hidden 2">Content description 2</p>
          <p class="description hidden 3">Content description 3</p>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var $container = $('#products-content');

$container.masonry({
    gutter: 0,
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-item',

       }); 

 var $item = $('.grid-item');

     $item.on('click', function(){

    $(this).children().removeClass('hidden');
    $container.masonry();

})
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite clear what you want - are you wanting the description in the grid-item div or below the list of `p`s?  Also, where is your content description coming from - is it hard coded or from a db?